# How do I send a function from content.js to the user's page in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I do console.log(true); in content.js, the page's console displays true. However, when I make a function

```
test = () => console.log(true);
```

and then use the function in the page's console, it says that the function is not defined. How can I send that function into the page?

FULL CODE:

```js
console.log(true); // prints true
var test = () => console.log(true); // console says test is undefined
window.test = test;
```

Comment: What if you try adding this line: `window.test = test`

Comment: It still says that window.test is undefined, and test itself does not work either.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add var at the beginning of the function. And you have to call it as test()

```
var test = () => console.log(true);
test();
//should return true
```

Comment: Perhaps I have a fundamental error because that does not work either, test is still undefined.

Comment: var test = () => console.log(true)
test() should log true